# SQL server multiple rows as multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, common-table-expression

My test data is as below:

There is an uniqueidentifier column also in the table.

```
**Month       Cost**

Jan         1000
Feb         1500
May         1200
```

The result I am expecting is in format

```
Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May 
1000    1500    NULL    NULL    1200
```

any approach of Pivot or CTE or normal query is OK.

Comment: As always, what have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If months are always 12 you can use pivot easily (not tested):

```
SELECT 
   P.[Jan],P.[Feb],P.[Mar],P.[Apr] 
FROM 
   TABLE
PIVOT 
   (MAX (Cost) for [Month] in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr])) AS P
```

If you need to create a dynamic one you must generate sql code and then run it with exec

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never knew it would be so simple

Answer (score 1):

You can convert rows to columns

```
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='JAN' THEN Cost END) AS JAN,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='Feb' THEN Cost END) AS Feb,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='MAR' THEN Cost END) AS MAR,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='APR' THEN Cost END) AS APR,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='MAY' THEN Cost END) AS MAY,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='JUN' THEN Cost END) AS JUNE,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='JUL' THEN Cost END) AS JUL,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='AUG' THEN Cost END) AS AUG,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='SEP' THEN Cost END) AS SEP,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='OCT' THEN Cost END) AS OCT,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='NOV' THEN Cost END) AS NOV,
    MIN(CASE WHEN [MONTH]='DEC' THEN Cost END) AS DEC
    FROM YOURTABLE
```

If you want sum of values you can change `MIN` to `SUM`

Comment: is it better than pivot?

Comment: plan's cost is the same, pivot is more compact but I think that it is the same stuff